# int 21 equivalent in C++ windows XP

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

Interrupts are not working in inline-assembler of C++(i tried VC++ 10, GCC 4, Digital Mars). Is there any interrupt-equivalent windows free-to-access memory areas? How can i reach system properties and video ram?(can i?)

These i would like to know:

```
mov ah,06h
mov dl,35h 
int 21f    //would print '5' on screen but it isnt (works in only pure assembler)
```

and:

```
mov ax,1500h
mov ch,97h
int 2f   //would get me info for the cache-hit number on DI:SI
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Win32 applications don't call interrupts, they call system services.  There's a number of assembly for Windows tutorials on [Iczelion's page](http://win32assembly.online.fr/tutorials.html).

Comment: And usermode system services [call INT 2Eh or SYSENTER](http://opcode0x90.wordpress.com/2007/05/18/kifastsystemcall-hook)